# Inequality problem: $(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)^2 \le n^2 (a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2)$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n \in R^+$, then prove that
$$(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)^2 \le n^2 (a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2)$$
I attempted to solve this problem but was unable to.I used the Cauchy Schwarz Inequality for the two sets $\{1,1,1, \dots\}$ and $\{a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n\}$ but the result was $$(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)^2 \le n(a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2).$$
Could you please help me in solving this problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Questions like "Here is the task. Solve it for me!" are poorly received on this site. Therefore try to improve your question with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2942431/edit). Improving could consist of providing some context concerning your task or by adding what you have tried so far and where did you struggle :)

Comment: Hint: $n\leq n^2$.

Comment: Thank you for the hint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While your attempt leads to an answer, as explained in a comment, by noting $n \le n^2$, there is a way that seems more elementary to me:

Let $a_m$ be the largest of the $a_i$, then 
$$(a_1+a_2+\dots+a_n)^2 \le (na_m)^2 = n^2 a_m^2 \le n^2 (a_1^2+a_2^2+\dots+a_n^2) $$